# html open a url on new target and focus

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fix a web site.

It opens a help page in a new window/tab via `<a href="..." target="help">` (no other frame has this name)

This works well the first time opening a new window/tab, for the help.
But on subsequent clicks the window/tab is loaded but remains hidden.

I tried this:

```
<script>
    function OpenAndFocusHelp() {
        win=window.open('help/1000CH00017.htm','help');
        win.focus();
    }      
</script>

<a href="help.html" target="help" 
   onclick="OpenAndFocusHelp()">Help</a>
```

It did not work!

Comment: So the window is loading, just not showing? Is it loading the correct page? Does it have the same behavior in every browser? I think this is a window manager concern, not something you can do from javascript, but I'm starring for now, I want to follow along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this feature is browser-specific and you can't define the behavior for focusing new tabs or windows..

Answer (score 7):

It seems that modern browsers do not allow you to `window.focus` an existing window.  Or at least, it will not give that window focus.  (IE9 will actually blink the tab, but most other browsers merely load it but give no indication that the user's attention should be drawn to the new window.)

Therefore, one solution that presents itself is to close the window first, and then re-open it immediately after.  For example, [declare the following function](http://jsfiddle.net/aqxBy/7/):

```
window.openOrFocus = function(url, name) {
    if (!window.popups)
        window.popups = {};
    if (window.popups[name])
        window.popups[name].close();
    window.popups[name] = window.open(url, name);
}
```

Now, you can write HTML such as this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openOrFocus('http://jsfiddle.net/k3t6x/2/', 'window1')">Window 1</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openOrFocus('http://jsfiddle.net/KR6w3/1/', 'window2')">Window 2</a><br />
```

Since it closes the window first, it reliably gives focus to the newly created child window.

*This solution also uses the `window.popups` namespace, so rename the usages of that in the javascript sample if you have a function named `popups` or have otherwise collided with it.*

**Caveat**: This does not work after a post-back.  This is because once you navigate away from the current page, it is no longer the owner of the child windows.  Therefore, it can no longer close them.  However, it merely degrades to the usual (non-focusing) behavior of using the `target` attribute.

**Tested In:** Firefox 4, Chrome 11, IE 9
**JsFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aqxBy/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can have such code instead:

```
var _arrAllWindows = new Array();
function OpenOrFocus(oLink, sTarget) {
    var oWindow = _arrAllWindows[sTarget];
    if (!oWindow || oWindow.closed) {
        oWindow = window.open(oLink.href, sTarget);
        _arrAllWindows[sTarget] = oWindow;
    }
    oWindow.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Then to call it, have such link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return OpenOrFocus(this, 'help');">Open</a>
```

Works fine in Chrome and IE, unfortunately Firefox disable by default the option to "raise" windows in code so `focus()` has no effect in that browser - could not find any work around.

Test case is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/eVxJX/

Comment: @richard: what browser? does it happen in the jsfiddle sample as well?

Comment: The example in http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/eVxJX/ works for chome not firefox as mentioned above. Will retest with ie when back at work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using jQuery and HTML5 with fallback for JavaScript-disabled clients. It will reload pages on every click. Tested and works in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-popup]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open(this.href, this.dataset['popup'], 'resizable,scrollbars').focus();
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" data-popup="stackoverflow">Stack Overflow</a>
<a href="https://superuser.com/" target="_blank" data-popup="superuser">Super User</a>
<a href="https://serverfault.com/" target="_blank" data-popup="serverfault">Server Fault</a>
```