# window.focus() or window.close() not working on windows opened with google domain url

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to reuse opened windows and to do that i want to use the .focus() method (or .close() and reopen new). While working i noticed that when i use urls with google domain, the methods stop working on Firefox (109.0.1 (64-bit)) and Chrome (Version 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (x86_64)). I'm using MacOS BigSur 11.7.

However, on Safari (6.3 (16614.4.6.11.4, 16614)) it works.

ex urls that did not work: https://www.google.com/, https://translate.google.com/, https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=44.6514203255951,-63.57586876433356

[focus method answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240810/18298695) - I used this example to create my own way to test the problem explained above:

```
<script>
    window.openOrFocus = function(url, name, style = "width=500,height=500") {
        if (!window.popups)
            window.popups = {};
        if (window.popups[name]){
            window.popups[name].focus();
        } else{
            window.popups[name] = window.open(url, name, style);
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick='window.openOrFocus("https://www.google.com/","google","width=500,height=500");'>Open/focus GOOGLE window</a></br>
<a href="#" onclick='window.openOrFocus("https://www.youtube.com/","youtube","width=500,height=500");'>Open/focus YOUTUBE window</a>
```

I placed some console logs and on Firefox i get a 'Restricted' on window.popups and using chrome i noticed that the param closed is true on google window even if it is not closed yet.

Comment: Are you saying that you are having this problem _just_ with Google URLs, but not with other, 3rd-party ones? Because you _should_ have it for all, if I am interpreting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#same-origin_policy correctly.

Comment: I've tried with multiple other URLs and even in the example above, the youtube one worked for me and the google did not. And yes, i expected it to not work on neither as the documentation you provided says.

Comment: Something to do with what specifically these sites allow via HTTP response headers then perhaps, I suppose.